# Fullcalendar with Angular, triggering ViewRender

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

The issue is triggering an event when the current view of Fullcalendar changes. For instance, when the month changes to previous or the next one. Using **ViewRender** did not help.
In multiple resources, the recommended solution was **ViewRender**, however I could not find the angular implementation, therefore, my implementation might be mistaken. Furthermore, using view and element parameters with the function did not help either.

My function is as following:

```
eventViewRender() {
  console.log("Working here");
}
```

My HTML markup is as following:

```
<full-calendar
      defaultView="dayGridMonth"
      [weekends]="options.calendarWeekends"
      [events]="eventsModel"
      (select)="multiSelected($event)"
      (eventDrop)="eventDragStop($event)"
      [plugins]="options.plugins"
      (viewRender)="eventViewRender()"
></full-calendar>
```

Comment: Why do you need to trigger an event when the view changes? What are you hoping to do when that happens? (I only ask this because many people try to do that for the wrong reasons and often a better implementation exists).

Comment: Anyway, you didn't mention which version of fullCalendar you're using? In the latest version (v5) then viewRender doesn't exist - check this documentation instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks

Comment: In v4 it would be this instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/viewSkeletonRender . "viewRender" hasn't existed since v3. When looking for examples online please check they are relevant to your version and then if they aren't, please go and read the documentation for your version because more than likely it will show you what to do instead.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reaction! I use the version 4.4 and my wish is to fetch data relevant to the selected month. viewSkeletonRender only worked at the initial paint of the calendar and not when the month changes. I can achieve my goal by using methods reacting to button clicks, but I believe there should be a better way to implement.

Comment: "my wish is to fetch data relevant to the selected month"...you don't need any kind of viewRender callback for that. Instead, configure your event source correctly and fullCalendar will handle it for you automatically - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed (or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function if you need more flexibility). If you tell fullCalendar where to look for new events, then it will request them for you whenever the view or date changes.

Comment: Huge thanks. I believe this will answer my issue. And I'll also consider your previous recommendations in the future. Thanks again

Comment: No problem. P.S. As it happens I think fullCalendar maybe need to improve their documentation or provide some more detailed examples/tutorials or something, because so many people asking on Stackoverflow make this same mistake, assuming they need to handle the change of view themselves in order to load new events. I only know how it's supposed to be done because I've worked with the calendar for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of my calendar component.
The part where you return the list of new events is delegated to an @Input that points to a function.
It is not the most beautiful solution and I expect to understand from those who are more experienced than me how to improve it

```
 export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() id: string
  @Input() ariaLabel: string
  @Input() height: string
  @Input() locale: string
  @Input() tabIndex: number
  @Input() callBack: (e, s, f) => {} = (e, s, f) => []
  @Input() view: 'timeGridWeek' | 'dayGridMonth' | 'dayGridWeek'
  @Input() events: QuixCalendarEvent[] = []
  @Input() header: { [key: string]: any }
  @Input() footer: { [key: string]: any }
  @Input() buttonsIcons: { [key: string]: any } = {
    close: 'fas fa-times',
    prev: 'fas fa-chevron-left',
    next: 'fas fa-chevron-right',
    prevYear: 'fas fa-angle-double-left',
    nextYear: 'fas fa-angle-double-right'
  }
  @Output() onEventClick = new EventEmitter<any>()
  @Output() onDateClick = new EventEmitter<any>()
  @Output() onViewChange = new EventEmitter<any>()
  calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
    initialView: this.view,
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    events: this.viewChange.bind(this),
    height: '',
    eventClick: this.eventClick.bind(this),
    dateClick: this.dateClick.bind(this),
    headerToolbar: this.header,
    footerToolbar: this.footer,
    buttonIcons: this.buttonsIcons,
    locale: '',
  };

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges
  ) {
    if (changes.height?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.height = changes.height.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.view?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.initialView = changes.view?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.header?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.headerToolbar = changes.header?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.footer?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.footerToolbar = changes.footer?.currentValue
    }
    if (changes.locale?.currentValue) {
      this.calendarOptions.locale = changes.locale?.currentValue
    }
  }

  eventClick(event: any) {
    this.onEventClick.emit(event)
  }

  dateClick(event: any) {
    this.onDateClick.emit(event)
  }

  viewChange(event: any, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    this.onViewChange.emit(event)
    this.callBack(event, successCallback, failureCallback)
  }

}
```